# I am tring to move my filtering logic from EnhanceTable.tsx to PopOvers.tsx unsucessful though

Tags: reactjs, filter, material-ui

This is my sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-curran-fsn3d?file=/src/EnhancedTable.tsx

I just wanted to move the logic of filtering(in EnhanceTable.tsx) which is between line 354 - 363 for the input there
it's working for me in EnhanceTable.tsx but I need to modify the modal(PopOver.tsx) to have the filtering logic.